# Detect Time Travel

Tags: code-golf, date

Computers are everywhere nowadays - in cars, trains, skateboards, even nuclear reactors. The possibility that your software will run in a time travelling device is just a matter of time. Can you deal with it? Can you at least detect it?

Your task:

1. Write a program that loops and keeps querying the system time, in order to detect time travel.
2. If time moves forward a day or more between two consecutive queries, it's forward time travel. In this case, your program should print:
   `TS TS: YYYY? You mean we're in the future?`
3. If time moves back, by any amount, between two consecutive queries, it's backward time travel. In this case, your program should print:
   `TS TS: Back in good old YYYY.`
4. `TS TS` are the timestamps before and after the time travel. `YYYY` is the destination year.
5. Timestamps may be in any format, that includes at least the 4-digit year, month, day, hour, minute and second, separated by non-digits.

Limitations:

1. You must support dates in the 19th, 20th and 21st centuries, at least.
2. You must use a language that existed before this challenge was posted.
3. You must post your answers only after this challenge was posted.
4. You must use a language that existed before your answer was posted.
5. You may edit your answer only after you've posted it.
6. Your program must not print any output other than the required output. An occasional "Great Scott!" is allowed.

This is code-golf. The shortest answer wins.
Relevant movie references will probably make your answer too long, but might get you upvotes.

Comment: [More falsehoods programmers believe about time, #36](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time): "*Time always goes forwards.*"

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about #5?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that each message should be followed by a newline?

Comment: So, my computer jumps in time whenever I set it to sleep mode? Also, once per year due to the daylight saving time?

Comment: system time is local time or UTC?

Comment: separated by nondigits? boo. YYYYMMDDHHmmSS is my favorite timestamp format.

Comment: @Dennis, yes, it seems obvious to me, but I should clarify.

Comment: @SztupY, Whatever you wish. Pacific Daylight Saving Time is also good.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Sleep would break this algorithm. But you have to start somewhere. I should have dealt with daylight saving by requiring backward travel to be more than an hour, but I won't edit now because it will break existing answers.

Comment: @Sparr, It must be both separated and with nondigits. In your format the nondigits don't separate anything.

Comment: @ugoren I recognize that, and I don't like it. Hence the "boo".

Comment: @Doorknob, If my question made 11 people (as of now) read your link, I think I did a good job.

Comment: What if I change my computer's system time, that's not time travel!

Comment: @Aequitas how do you know? maybe the system clock is actually immutable and "setting" it is actuallly time traveling

Comment: Limitation 2,3,4,5 are really harsh, I don't know if I can handle that.

Comment: +1 for posing a problem that seems to be unsuitable to be solved with a few chars in one of the esoteric golf scripting languages!

Comment: @FelixDombek, Yet [CJam is the leader](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61367/3544)...

Comment: Wait, no references to Doctor Who in the question? What is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CJam, 118 bytes

```
et:Tes{es_@-[TS*Set:TS*':S]\_864e5<{[1$et0="? You mean we're in the future?"N]o}|0<{[_"Back in good old "et0='.N]o}&}g
```

This does not work with the online interpreter.

Sample output after adjusting my computer's time twice:

```
2015 10 21 11 2 45 1 3 -10800000 2015 10 23 11 2 45 0 5 -10800000: 2015? You mean we're in the future?
2015 10 23 11 2 53 448 5 -10800000 2015 10 21 11 2 52 0 3 -10800000: Back in good old 2015.
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work with the online interpreter (except that it doesn't let you fiddle with the time)?

Comment: Because this is an infinite loop, and the online interpreter shows output only after the program has finished.

Comment: So how do you test that it works?

Comment: Using the [Java interpreter](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/).

Answer (score 10):

### Python 2, 210 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
o=0
while 1:n=datetime.now();o=o or n;print"%s;%s: %s? You mean we're in the future?"%(o,n,n.year)if(n-o).days>=1else"%s;%s: Back in good old %s."%(n,o,n.year)if(n<o)else"Great Scott!";o=n
```

Timestamps are printed in in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, separated with semicolons. Switched to Python 2 from 3 since it's 2 chars shorter to print. Spams stdout with `Great Scott!` for <s>normies</s> non-time-travellers, since it's easier and cheaper to do that than set up a conditional print.

Comment: Does it expect the time as input? This is not what's asked (maybe it's vague). Also, it seems to print blank lines when time behaves well.

Comment: I meant asking the OS, not the user. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 263 bytes

```
n=Date;o=n.now();(function g(){k=new n;j=new n(o);s=`${k} ${o} `;if(n.now()-o>86400)console.log(`${s}${k.getFullYear()}? You mean we're in the future?`);if(o-n.now()>84600){console.log(`${s}Back in good old ${k.getFullYear()}.`);}o=n.now();setTimeout(g,100);}());
```

This could probably do with some rewriting to make it more efficient/small.

Source:

```
n=Date;
o=n.now();

(function go() {
   k=new n;
   j=new n(o);
   s=`${k} ${o} `;
   if (n.now() - o > 86400) {
      console.log(`${s}${k.getFullYear()}? You mean we're in the future?`);
   }
   if (o - n.now() > 84600) {
      console.log(`${s}Back in good old ${k.getFullYear()}.`);
   }
   o=n.now()
   setTimeout(go,100);
}());
```

Comment: Backwards travel is defined as moving back by any amount, not one day. Also, due to the multiple `now()` calls it may miss a travel event.

Comment: An attempt at golfing this:

    n=Date,o=n.now();setInterval("d=new n,s=d+\` ${new n(o)} \`;f=d.getFullYear();if(n.now()-o>8.64e+7)console.log(s+f+\`? You mean we're in the future?\`);if(o>n.now())console.log(s+\`Back in good old ${f}.\`);o=n.now()",100);

Comment: I think you can golf the first part to `o=(n=Date).now()`.

Comment: +Stefnotch `8.64e+7` is two characters longer than `86400`.

Comment: @towerofnix Use the `@` symbol to ping someone.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Oops! I was wondering why it didn't work.

Comment: @Stefnotch See above, `8.64e+7` is two characters longer than `86400`.

Comment: @towerofnix Well, Date.now() returns milliseconds. 86400 ms is not one day: https://www.google.com/search?q=milliseconds+to+days&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Also, update the code please?

Comment: @towerofnix I managed to golf it even more:
n=Date;o=n.now();setInterval("d=new n,s=d+\` ${new n(o)} \`;f=d.getFullYear();n.now()-o>8.64e+7&&console.log(s+f+\`? You mean we're in the future?\`);o>n.now()&&console.log(s+\`Back in good old ${f}.\`);o=n.now()",100) //Would it be ok to crash the browser? (Having a function that calls itself/a loop without any delay.)

Comment: Saved 4 more bytes:
n=Date;z=n.now;o=z();setInterval("d=new n,s=d+\` ${new n(o)} \`;f=d.getFullYear();n.now()-o>8.64e+7&&console.log(s+f+\`? You mean we're in the future?\`);o>z()&&console.log(s+\`Back in good old ${f}.\`);o=z()",100)

Comment: If you're using ES6, I'm pretty sure you could save a few bytes here by using arrow functions. (Though it looks like others have already eliminated the function part entirely by passing strings to setInterval instead.)

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + coreutils, 177

```
d()(date -d@"$@")
for((b=`date +%s`;a=`date +%s`;b=a)){
t=`d $a`\ `d $b`
((a<b))&&d $b "+$t: Back in good old %Y."
((a>b+86400))&&d $b "+$t: %Y? You mean we're in the future?"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 195

```
from datetime import*
n=datetime.now
p=n()
while 1:
 c=n();f=(p,c,p.year);s=(0,("%s %s: %s? You mean we're in the future?"%f,"%s %s: Back in good old %s."%f)[p.day>c.day])[p>c];p=c
 if s:print(s)
```

Currently doesn't print Great Scott because I can't find a good way of only making it occasional.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua 5.3, <s>179</s> <s>178</s> <s>173</s> <s>171</s> <s>169</s> <s>168</s> 163 bytes

```
q="%Y %c: "c=os.date::a::d=f f=os.time()_=d and(f-d>86399or f<d)and print(c(q,d)..c(q..(f<d and"Back in good old %Y."or"%Y? You mean we're in the future?")))goto a
```

Side note: If you take out the need for a full year number then subtract six bytes. The reason is that lua's (or windows' or someone's!) %c doesn't output the full year. Because of this, the timestamps may look weird!

This also takes advantage of timestamps being able to be seperated by any non digit characters!

Thanks for notifying me of my old math.abs reference and other improvements @thenumbernine :)

## Lua 5.3, 151 bytes

This is 'copying' off of @thenumbernine's method of displaying time by just showing the timestamp instead of the actual date. This isn't competitive since I think it is a bit of cheating, just posting it here to display my work :)

```
::a::d=f f=os.time()_=d and(f-d>86399or f<d)and print(d.." "..f..os.date(f<d and": Back in good old %Y."or": %Y? You mean we're in the future?"))goto a
```

Comment: We posted both our Lua answers at nearly the exact same time.  That has to say something about time travel.

Comment: Ahah, Thanks @thenumbernine! I finally got my ability to comment :)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua 5.3, 174 bytes

```lua
T=os.time P=print l=T()::a::t=T()b=l.." "..t..": "y=os.date('%Y',t)_=t<l and
P(b.."Back in good old "..y)or t>l+86399 and
P(b..y.."? You mean we're in the future?")l=t goto a
```

This is playing heavily off of the "Timestamps may be in any format" rule ... which I took the liberty of using the format of "seconds since Jan 1, 1970"



If I keep my shoddy interpretation of printing timestamps, and adopt the structure of MeepDarknessMeep, I can (unethically) squeeze this down to ...

## 155 bytes

```lua
T=os.time::G::l=t or T()t=T()_=(t>l+86399or t<l)and
print(l.." "..t..": "..os.date(t<l
and"Back in good old %Y"or"%Y? You mean we're in the future?"))goto G
```

Comment: `Timestamps may be in any format, that includes at least the 4-digit year, month, day, hour, minute and second, separated by non-digits.` - that doesn't allow seconds since epoch.

Comment: good thing it didn't "exclude" any formats

Comment: @ugoren Really that requirement should be more specific as to your intention

Comment: I'm not fully familiar with lua so I may be wrong, but it looks like this prints `Back in good ol YYYY` but it should print `Back in good old YYYY`.  (Note the d in old)

Comment: nope good catch, I was trying to shave bytes wherever I could :-p

Comment: @mego I was going to use the (days since 2000) for a [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu) answer, but I saw this :o

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 194 bytes

I haven't had the time to really cut this down to size yet. I'm sure there are a few optimizations hiding in there.

```
require 'time';t=nil;while 1;n=Time.now;if t;s="#{t} #{n}: ";y=n.year;puts t>n ? "#{s}Back in good old #{y}" : (n>t+86400 ? "#{s}#{y}? You mean we're in the future?": "Great Scott!");end;t=n;end
```

Ungolfed (and a lot more readable):

```
require 'time'
t=nil
while 1
  n=Time.now
  if t                                             # on second or later pass
    s="#{t} #{n}: "                                # prepare the timestamp
    y=n.year
    puts t>n ?                                     # if we go back
      "#{s}Back in good old #{y}" :                # timestamp + phrase
      (n>t+86400 ?                                 # else, more than one day forward
        "#{s}#{y}? You mean we're in the future?": # timestamp + future
        "Great Scott!")                            # Great Scott!
  end
  t=n                                              # set a new jump point
end
```

Edit: corrected to ask OS for time, rather than a human.

Comment: A few recommendations: Use `loop{}` instead of `while 1...end`, and try using `+` for string concatenation instead of interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <strike>170</strike> 165 bytes

```
from datetime import*
n=datetime.now
c=n()
while 1:
 p=c;c=n()
 if(c-p).days:print p,"%s:"%c,["%s? You mean we're in the future?","Back in good old %s."][c<p]%c.year
```

This owes a lot to Morgan Thrapp's answer.  The main trick here is timedelta normalization, which conveniently makes timedelta.days negative when moving even slightly towards the past, and 0 when moving less than a day to the future.

Comment: After `import*` you don't need the `datetime.` prefix.

Comment: @ugoren: `import*` allows one to write `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`.  It kind of makes sense, in a way...

Comment: In a confusing way, it does.

Answer (score 1):

## Caché ObjectScript, 199 bytes

```
l s k=86400 f  s e=+$H,t=$P($H,",",2) s:'d d=e,s=t s z=$ZDT(h)_" "_$ZDT($H)_": ",y=h\365+1841 w:e>d !,z,y,"? You mean we're in the future?" w:(k*t+e)<(k*s+d) !,z,"Back in good old ",y s h=$H,d=e,s=t
```

This problem is solvable in plain old MUMPS, but would be unreasonably lengthy, since ANSI MUMPS lacks [the `$ZD[ATE]T[IME]` intrinsic function](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20091/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fzdatetime) for formatting dates into human-readable timestamps.

This program will probably not detect time-travel to before 1 Jan 1841, nor time-travel to after 31 Dec 9999, since these are the bounds of [the `$H[OROLOG]` timekeeping intrinsic](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20091/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_vhorolog). This program also only has second-level precision; sub-second-level backwards time glitches will likely escape its notice.

Answer (score 1):

### TSQL, 355 bytes

At the work so no fancy cool languges stick with your SQL Server production server =)

Golfed version

```
declare @a datetime=getdate(),@b datetime,@d float,@ char(99),@y char(4)while 0=0begin select @b=getdate(),@d=cast(@b as float)-cast(@a as float),@y=' '+DATEPART(y,@b),@=cast(@a as char(20))+' '+cast(@a as char(20))+': 'if @d>=1set @=@+@y+'? You mean we''re in the future?'if @d<0set @=@+'Back in good old '+@y+'.'print @ set @a=@b end
```

More readable version with minor changes.

```
declare @t0 datetime = getdate(), @t1 datetime, @d float, @m varchar(99), @y char(4)

while 0=0
begin

    set @t1 = getdate()
    set @d = cast(@t1 as float) - cast(@t0 as float)
    set @y = ' ' + DATEPART(yy, @t1)
    set @m = cast(@t0 as varchar(30)) + ' ' + cast(@t0 as varchar(30)) + ': '

    if @d >= 1 set @m = @m + @y + '? You mean we''re in the future?'
    if @d < 0 set @m = @m +  'Back in good old ' + @y + '.'

    print @m

    set @t0 = @t1
end
```

SQL is not that bad in respect to timestamps since it's a first class data type.

For the golf's sake we are using a type with 3 milliseconds precision. The loop itself takes less that that to iterate (depending of your server). The key here is internaly that time stamp is a float and the integer type counts how many days passed. It ill work fine in January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999 date range.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 258 Bytes

#### Ran with:Excel 2007 in Windows 7

**305 bytes** if Usability is required

> WARNING This MAY Max your CPU and Crash Excel/Windows if you are on a Single Threaded single core computer (Most likely found in 1985)

```
Sub q()
h=CDbl(Now())
While 1
t=CDbl(Now())
If t>h+1 Then Debug.Print (CDate(t) & " " & CDate(h) & ":" & Year(t) & "? You mean we're in the future?")
If t<h Then Debug.Print (CDate(t) & " " & CDate(h) & ": Back in good old " & Year(t) & ".")
h=t
Wend
End Sub
```

If you want this Code to be "Testable" then add `Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` after `h=t`

#### Output

```
10/22/2015 3:04:45 PM 10/22/2015 3:04:43 PM:2015?You mean we're in the future?
10/22/2015 3:06:48 PM 10/22/2015 3:06:46 PM: Back in good old 2015.
```

Below is the test file I used. I'm Honestly Amazed at how little security Windows has sometimes. May not run as expected on all computers

> Run at Own Risk Could Have Major lasting Side Effects!!!!
>  `Sub DOC()
>  t = 31346.6868055556
>  Date = DateSerial(Year(t), Month(t), Day(t))
>  Time = TimeSerial(Hour(t), Minute(t), Second(t))
>  q
>  End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) <strike>181</strike> <strike>174</strike> 170 Bytes

```
for(a=Date;c=b||a.now(),b=d();e=new a(b).getFullYear(),f=`${a(c)} ${a(b):`})b>c+864e5?(g=alert)`${f} ${e}? You mean we're in the future?`:c>b&&g`${f} Back in good old `+e
```

**Note:** Has not been tested with a real time machine.

This code runs in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Node.js Harmony (or [io.js](http://iojs.org) for that matter). But, I use `alert`, so that will have to be replaced by `console.log` for [Node](http://nodejs.org) and [Io](http://iojs.org) Suport: (187 Bytes)

```
for(a=Date,b=0;c=b||(d=a.now)(),b=d();e=new a(b).getFullYear(),f=`${a(c)} ${a(b):`})b>c+864e5?(g=console.log)`${f} ${e}? You mean we're in the future?`:c>b&&g`${f} Back in good old ${e}.`
```

Explained:

```
// Using for like a while loop, defining relevant variables:
  for (a = Date, b = 0;
// Defing b and c: c becomes b, b becomes now. Also defining a shorthand for Date.now:                                
  c = b || a.now(),
  b = d();
// Defining Variables Relevant to this loop: e is the year according to b, f is the "TS TS:" string:                        
  e = new a(b).getFullYear(),
  f = `${a(c)} ${a(b):`
  )
// If b is greater than c plus a day (in milliseconds):
  b > c + 864e5 ?
  // Alert Time Forwand String: 
    (g = alert)
    `${f} ${e}? You mean we're in the future?`:
// else if c is greater than b:
  c > b &&
  // Alert Time Back String: 
    g `${f} Back in good old `+e
```

Comment: I managed to write an even shorter one, you might want to have a look at it and possibly make yours better. Also, I think it is great!

Comment: How big was your solution, I want to see if I can beat it? ;)

Comment: Scroll down or click on the link: codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61544/33160 Also, you are pretty close to beating it! :D

Answer (score 1):

## C: 363 bytes

Minified using [this handy script](https://github.com/Scylardor/cminify/blob/master/minifier.py):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
void p(time_t*t){char b[64];strftime(b,64,"%FT%T",localtime(t));printf("%s ",b);}int main(void){time_t a,b,d=60*60*24;int y;time(&a);while(1){time(&b);y=localtime(&b)->tm_year+1900;if(b<a){p(&a);p(&b);printf("Back in good old %d\n",y);}else if(b>a+d){p(&a);p(&b);printf("%d? You mean we're in the future?\n",y);}a=b;sleep(1);}}
```

Original:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void p(time_t * t) {
  char b[64];
  strftime(b, 64, "%FT%T", localtime(t));
  printf("%s ", b);
}

int main(void) {
  time_t a, b, d = 60*60*24;
  int y;

  time(&a);
  while(1) {
    time(&b);
    y = localtime(&b)->tm_year+1900;
    if (b < a) {
      p(&a); p(&b); printf("Back in good old %d\n", y);

    } else if (b > a + d) {
      p(&a); p(&b); printf("%d? You mean we're in the future?\n", y);
    }
    a = b;
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Example run:

```
2015-10-23T23:30:03 1985-06-14T16:27:00 Back in good old 1985   
1985-06-14T16:27:07 1999-02-09T14:15:00 1999? You mean we're in the future?
1999-02-09T14:15:09 2015-02-09T14:15:00 2015? You mean we're in the future?
2015-02-09T14:15:36 2015-10-21T07:28:00 2015? You mean we're in the future?
2015-10-21T07:29:06 1985-10-26T09:00:00 Back in good old 1985
1985-10-26T09:00:28 2055-11-12T06:38:00 2055? You mean we're in the future?
2055-11-12T06:38:12 1919-10-07T00:09:57 Back in good old 1919
1919-10-07T00:09:57 2055-11-12T06:38:14 2055? You mean we're in the future?  # tried to go to 1955 - fail.
2055-11-12T06:39:09 2015-10-23T23:32:03 Back in good old 2015  # auto-time back to 2015 because my laptop didn't like the jump to 2055!
```

I could get rid of 10 bytes by removing the `sleep` I guess.

By the way, some time-jumping handiness for Mac/Linux:

```
sudo date 1026090085  # Sat 26 Oct 1985 09:00:00
sudo date 1021072815  # Wed 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00
sudo date 1112063855  # Intended to be 1955 but is 2055. Don't use!
```

Comment: Feel free to drop the `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

### Processing, 270 bytes

```
int p;long x=System.currentTimeMillis();void draw(){int q=millis(),y=year();if(q<p){t(p);print("Back in good old "+y+".");}if(q>p+86400000){t(p);print(y+"? You mean we're in the future?");}p=q;}void t(int m){print(new java.util.Date(x+m)+" "+new java.util.Date()+": ");}
```

Expanded:

```
int p;
long x=System.currentTimeMillis();
void draw() {
  int q=millis(), y=year();
  if (q<p) {
    t(p);
    print("Back in good old "+y+".");
  }
  if (q>p+86400000) {
    t(p);
    print(y+"? You mean we're in the future?");
  }
  p=q;
}
void t(int m) {
  print(new java.util.Date(x+m)+" "+new java.util.Date()+": ");
}
```

Sample output:

```
Wed Oct 21 13:21:59 EDT 2015 Mon Oct 19 13:21:59 EDT 2015: Back in good old 2015.
Mon Oct 19 13:22:08 EDT 2015 Wed Oct 21 13:22:08 EDT 2015: 2015? You mean we're in the future
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript <strike>173 169</strike> 162 bytes

Javascript is pretty popular...

```
for(e=Date,n=e.now;o=n(a=alert);)d=new e,f=d.getFullYear(n(o>n(s=d+` ${e(o)}:`)&&a(s+`Back in good old ${f}.`))-o>864e5&&a(s+f+`? You mean we're in the future?`))
```

Explanation (Older version of the code):

```
for(e=Date,n=e.now,a=alert,o=n();;o=n()) //Set up the variables and update o, the previous time

d=new e,s=d+` ${e(o)} `,f=d.getFullYear(), //d is the date, s is a string with the 2 timestamps, f is the year
n()-o>8.64e7&&a(s+f+`? You mean we're in the future?`), //Future check
o>n()&&a(s+`Back in good old ${f}.`) //Past check
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>160</s> <s>157</s> <s>155</s> 154 bytes

A lot of things to golf here

```
a=Time.new;loop{b,s,y=Time.new,"#{a} #{b}: ",b.year;$><<(a>b ? s+"Back in good old #{y}.\n":b>a+86400 ? s+"#{y}? You mean we're in the future?\n":"");a=b}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 295 bytes

The program asks the OS every second for new TS.

```
f:=LocalTime[]
p=Print;
y:=DateString[#,"Year"]&
s:=ToString[#]<>" "&
d:=QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[a,b]
j=StringJoin;
While[True,
  a=b;
  b=f;
  Pause@1;
  Which[d>=0,
   p@(j@@{s@a,s@b,": ",y@b, 
       "? You mean we are in the future?"}),
   d<0,
   p@(j@@{s@a,s@b," Back in good old ",y@b,"."})]];
```

## Output

Tested by manually feeding in date/time.

```
DateObject[{2015, 10, 23}, TimeObject[{18, 36, 17.9618}], TimeZone -> \
-4.] DateObject[{2015, 10, 25}, TimeObject[{18, 42, 0.264913}], \
TimeZone -> -4.] : 2015? You mean we are in the future?

DateObject[{2015, 10, 23}, TimeObject[{18, 43, 0.141572}], TimeZone -> -4.] DateObject[{2015, 10, 23}, TimeObject[{18, 42, 3.30681}], TimeZone -> -4.]  Back in good old 2015.
```

Definitely could have format the output better. It does fulfill the requirements as stated.

Comment: why do you shortcut `LocalTime[]`? It appears only once in the following code.

Comment: At one point, I was using it twice. Good catch though.

Comment: Remove it and you save three characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 244 bytes

```
def s=9999,d={new Date()},y={it.year+1900},f={t,n->"$t $n: ${y(n)}? You mean we're in the future?"},p={t,n->"$t $n: Back in good old ${y(n)}."},t=d()
while(!sleep(s)){n=d()
c=n.time-t.time
println c<0?p(t,n):c>s*2?f(t,n):'Great Scott!'
t=n}
```